# iOS: AppStore installs old version and then offer to update to the new one

Tags: ios, app-store

I submitted a new version of my app to AppStore and it was approved a week ago.

However, I delete the app from the iPad, install it from AppStore and I get the old version installed. The "Install" button on AppStore turns to "Update" instead of "Launch" and then I get the new version installed.

Does anyone know what could be happen here? Why the new version is not installed in first place?

I tried with iOS 5 and iOS 6

Comment: We saw this as well with our app.  However, from what I have been able to find online it seems to be related to having TestFlight installed.  Were you using TestFlight on those devices? Maybe it is related?  We could never get a repro on a device without TestFlight installed.

Comment: I have run into this issue before as well, and we've never used TestFlight. What is even more frustrating is that on the app store under the "information" section it will display the latest version number etc. misleading you to believe that you are downloading the latest.

Comment: I am running into this on (at least) ios 7 on an iphone 5. We have used enterprise distribution before the app store version was released, it could be that only those phones are affected.

Answer (score 3):

**TestFlight or a Ad-Hoc network is almost always the cause of this problem.**

Also, when you back up via iCloud and sync back your apps they will not automatically update.

Revoke your app from Ad-Hoc and from TestFlight. It should update to the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

**This issue occurs only on obsolete iOS** like iOS 5 or iOS 6. If one tries on latest iOS 7, one may not face this issue. I've tested & faced same issue under iOS 6, but **I couldn't reproduce on iOS 7**.